# I've got an equation, but it seemed wrong, which step did I go wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\begin{align*}
\ln(\cos\theta)&=\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}}\\
&=\frac12\ln(2+2\cos2\theta)-\ln2\\
&=\frac12\ln(e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}+2)-\ln2\\
&=\frac12\ln(1+e^{i2\theta})+\frac12\ln(1+e^{-i2\theta})-\ln2\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{i2n\theta}}{n}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{-i2n\theta}}{n}-\ln2\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\cos2n\theta-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(\cos2n\theta-1)
\end{align*}
$

also,

$\begin{align*}
\ln(\cos\theta)&=\ln(1+\cos\theta-1)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(\cos\theta-1)^n\\
\end{align*}\\
\text{to ensure it's convergent, I assumed that }\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}) $

so I got

$\cos2n\theta-1=(\cos\theta-1)^n$ for $\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

but obviously they aren't equal, which step did I get wrong?

Comment: Just because $\sum a_n/n=\sum b_n/n,$  you can't conclude that $a_n=b_n.$